# Is there a way to implement Google Sign-in with a custom login prompt?

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication, google-authentication, google-signin

I'm following the [Google tutorial](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project) on how to implement Google Sign-in: aside RADIUS and Active Directory, I want to offer a Google-based login to my site.

For testing purpose I have two machines (host1 and host2): host2 has a `SimpleHTTPServer` Python module loaded with a web page where only the Sign-in button is showed, host1 connects to host2 and click to the button in order to be redirected to home page.

My usual login prompt is made of two empty rectangles where users enter their username and password (RADIUS and AD login), while with Google Sign-in they will not type in the rectangles but click Sign-in button and enter credentials in the new window that will open.

**I'd like to separate the credentials insertion from their sending to Google servers**: I'd like the users to be able to enter their Google username and password in the same login prompt I offer for RADIUS and AD login; then, I'add another login button next to the usual one, maybe with "Login with Google" written inside.

Comment: I doubt it.  If you could, you would be able to make a sign-in form that looks like Googles and capture the user/pass.

Comment: You mean that, with Google Sign-in button, there's no way I could see user/pass?

Comment: That's the idea, yes.  The users name/pass should never be available to any code you might write - including a UI.

Comment: I'll try with Firebase `signInWithRedirect()` method, and let you know

Comment: The whole point of OAuth is for users not to provide the 3rd party developer with their permanent credentials. What you are trying to accomplish is a very bad security practice and should be highly discouraged. Firebase Auth will not allow you to do so either. You are basically building a phishing site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot and should not be allowed to do this.

If you were able to, that would mean you could capture someone's Google credentials and successfully log them in so it appears to them they logged in with Google, when actually you stole their credentials. This is a massive security risk, so even if you found a way to make this work, Google will actively close your loopholes to increase their security.

Any third party authorization service needs to own the authentication process from beginning to end. If they allow people like you to inject themselves as a middleman passing credentials from the user to them, that totally defeats all their security measures.

You also shouldn't attempt to do this for the users' ease of use. If a user clicks 'Sign in with Google', one of two things happen; 1. They enter their Google credentials into Google's form, or 2. They are already logged into Google and they just give permission for your site to access whatever identity information your site needs. Now on subsequent logins, If I'm already logged in with Google (like I checked my Gmail or something), when I click 'Sign in with Google', I automatically sign in, no additional entry of user/password required! But if you inject your custom login form in the mix, now I'm required to enter my **exact same credentials** a **second time** to authorize myself with something I'm already authorized to. This is **incredibly annoying** and a user hostile design.

So basically, ***No*** and ***Don't***.

Comment: Very clear and understandable answer. What if I wish to offer an authentication service, but instead of using RADIUS _et similia_ (where custom credentials may be stored) I use Google credentials?
As you wrote, the login process must be entirely owned by Google so this means I can't see nor store credentials: is there no way to tell at least if Google username and password exist? Some way to tell "Your Google credentials exist, you may go on"?

Comment: How would you propose checking Google credentials without collecting them? I can't think of a way. And if you collect them then you see them/could store them...

Comment: As an aside it sounds like you're playing with microservices/multiple apps, where you would like to have only one of the apps handle authentication? You can't check someone's credentials, but what the auth service can do is handle the _tokens_ that Google auth returns. Then you just need to ask your auth handler, if this token the user possesses belongs to x user. The auth service then confirms with the token from Google according to the protocol. If they match, then they are who they say they are.